# Quotes and bunny ears

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to Python, going through a guide, and was wondering when you state the following (code below) what are the differences?

There seems to be a pattern here that maybe I'm not catching on and the more I push through the guide the more this question pops up in my head :)

```
print(' ')
print(" ")
print(   )

find(' ')
find(" ")
find(   )

urlopen(' ')
urlopen(" ")
urlopen(   )
```

Comment: in the first two cases you pass a string with a space to the functions/callables. In the third you pass nothing to the functions (i.e. no argument is passed explicitly)

Comment: Thank you, that is very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str), type `str`, in `Python 2` or `3` can be declared by using single quotes `' '` or double quotes `" "` (and triple quotes `""" """` which, generally, have a [special purpose](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#documentation-strings)). Python treats them similarly.

For the first two cases of your `print()` function, you are just passing the space character `' '` and `" "` and `print()` is just consequently just printing it. A similar logic applies to the other functions.

A function called with empty parenthesis `( )` just means that no arguments have been passed to it. What behavior this has (and ***if it is allowed***) is up to the definition of the function called.

---

For instance, the documentation for the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print) function states that:

> If no objects are given, print() will just write end.

With `end` here being specified as the new line sequence `\n`.

---

The only special cases where you need to use `" "` instead of `' '` is if your string contains `' '`. Vice-versa, you will need to use `' '` if your string contains `" "`.

So, for example:

```
print("This is a 'special' case") 
# prints: This is a 'special' case.

print("This is a "special" case") 
# error: invalid syntax
```

And vice versa:

```
print('This is a "special" case') 
# prints: This is a "special" case.

print('This is a 'special' case') 
# error: invalid syntax
```

Let's note that with triple quotes `""" """` you can have a string with both `' '` ***and*** `" "`:

```
print(""" this is a "special" 'special' case""") 
# prints: this is a "special" 'special' case
```

***Try these out*** to get a feel of them.

Comment: Thank You! 

So does that mean that ' and " are effectively the same? Where are they different?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the only possible case where you might want to differentiate between them :)